# Cannot set Gmail 'subject' and 'text' fields from an intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am calling an intent that sets the 'To' field no problem of a GMail template from a String array, but I cannot get it to set the 'subject' and 'text' fields.

Hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactsEmail extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    String emailPassed;
    String emailAdd;
    String emailSub;
    String emailMess;
    EditText setEmailAddress;
    EditText setEmailSubject;
    EditText setEmailMessage;
    Button btnSendEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.emaillayout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        emailPassed = extras.getString("passedEmailAdd"); 
    }

    setEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputEmailAddress);
    setEmailAddress.setText(emailPassed);
    setEmailSubject = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputEmailSubject);
    setEmailMessage = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputEmailMessage);

    emailAdd = setEmailAddress.getText().toString();
    emailSub = setEmailSubject.getText().toString();
    emailMess = setEmailMessage.getText().toString();

    btnSendEmail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendEmail);

    btnSendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View sendEmailClick) {
        Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sendEmailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {emailAdd});  
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSub); 
        sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailMess); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Send mail..."));   
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure emailSub and emailMess are not empty.

Comment: @TGMCians I set those variables with .getText().toString() of the EditTexts. So I dont believe they're empty

Comment: post the whole code to get know where is problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Actually When activity create you get the value of these editext. At that time value of these all are empty. so you need to write these in `onclick` method.

When you click on button then you will get the current edit text value.

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View sendEmailClick) {
    emailAdd = setEmailAddress.getText().toString();
    emailSub = setEmailSubject.getText().toString();
    emailMess = setEmailMessage.getText().toString();
    Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sendEmailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {emailAdd});  
    sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSub); 
    sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailMess); 
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Send mail..."));
}
```

and remove these three lines from `onCreate()` method.

```
emailAdd = setEmailAddress.getText().toString();
emailSub = setEmailSubject.getText().toString();
emailMess = setEmailMessage.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thats was the problem having those getTexts in the onCreate. Thanks again!

Comment: When i press the 'send' button on the gmail template it just reloads the class that i use to set the 'To' , 'subject' and 'message' fields. Have you any idea why?